# Input text field not showing on Ipad devices (Safari)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ipad, safari

I have an input field in which I use ui-mask on. I was doing some QA and noticed that it shows when entering text on Ipad devices on Safari, I can see caret moving positions but i cannot see any text. This works fine on desktop browsers and mobile devices like nexus 5, samsung s6 but on ipad safari it doesn't work as expected.

I saw something online as regards to setting -webkit-user-select to text. I tried this and still it didn't work on ipad.

Would appreciate anyone who has any idea on how to resolve this bug

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and fixed it:

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
    /* CSS specific to iOS devices */
    input, textarea {
        transform: translateZ(0px) !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but setting this rules to input's (well, page's actually) container helped in similar situation

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and for me the problem was that **I was forcing a fixed *height*** on the input element, effectively forcing the text of the input box to be hidden. You **must set *line-height*** as well to match the height.